# manipulating a numpy array with another array

Tags: numpy, 2d, numpy-indexing

I am doing my head in with brackets and ':' whilst trying to do 2 dimensional indexing with an other index
So I would be really pleased if somebody could straighten me out

I have an greyscale image
BlurredFlip shape is : (480, 640)
then I have used

```
minCoords = np.argmin(BlurredFlip, axis=0)
```

which has created a 1D array with, no surprise, the first row that has the minimum value for each column eg

```
minCoords = [292 289 289 287 287 .......
```

now I want to set to black every pixel beyond this row value - without using loops in python
the equivalent of

```
    BlurredFlip[292:479, 0] = 0
    BlurredFlip[289:479, 1] = 0
    BlurredFlip[289:479, 2] = 0
    BlurredFlip[287:479, 3] = 0

  and so on.
```

in pseudo code

```
for col in 1 to maxcol
   BlurredFlip[minCoords[col]:imageheight, col] = 0
```

I cant seem to get a way to reference the column twice like that.
But I can tell you many many ways to get the useless error *"TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"*

Thanks for any enlightenment :)

Comment: Can't you just do `BlurredFlip[292:479, :] = 0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution without using a for-loop. It might save you time, but not storage, if that is an issue. Given a 2D array `A` and a 1D array `row`. The dimension of `row` is the number of columns of `A`. For column `i` we set entries whose row number is greater than `row[i]` to zero. Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
AA  = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)+1;
row = np.asarray([0,1,2,3]);
rowidx, colidx = np.indices(AA.shape);
rowmask = rowidx > row;
AA[rowmask] = 0;
```

The output is

```
AA = array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 0,  0, 11, 12],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 16]])
```

The lower triangular part of the 2D array `AA` has been set to zero. The magic happens in the line `rowmask = rowidx > row`, which creates the mask. The rest is straight forward.

For your case, the solution is

```
rowidx,colidx = np.indices(BlurredFlip)
rowmask = rowidx > minCoords
BlurredFlip[rowmask] = 0
```

Comment: Nachiket - thats just the ticket! and thanks for taking the time to explain it my brain is one step closer to working multidimensionally :)

Comment: The magic that ```rowidx > row`` is based on is called Broadcasting